# Recursive UPDATE based the Values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which updates a table. This stored procedure is called using a daily job.

The logic int the stored procedure is as below:

```
Update Basetable
Set amount = Isnull(actualamount, 0)
From Acutaltable
Where jobcode Like '[%A-Z%]'

Update Basetable
Set amount = amount + Isnull(actualamount, 0)
From Acutaltable
Where jobcode Like '[%0-9%]'
```

The `jobcode` column is updated with dynamic values every day (i.e: `[%A-Z%]` jobcodes may be replace `[%0-9%]` jobcodes). So if any of the above update block failed, the stored procedure results in wrong output. I handled this by adding this code before each update.

```
UPDATE Basetable 
SET amount = NULL
```

Apart from this how to handle the above scenario?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with case when statement like the below,

```
UPDATE Basetable
SET amount = CASE 
        WHEN jobcode LIKE '[%A-Z%]'
            THEN ISNULL(actualamount, 0)
        WHEN jobcode LIKE '[%0-9%]'
            THEN amount + Isnull(actualamount, 0)
        ELSE NULL
        END
FROM Acutaltable
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE Basetable
SET amount = (CASE WHEN jobcode LIKE '[%A-Z%]' THEN  0 
WHEN jobcode LIKE '[%0-9%]'THEN amount END) + Isnull(actualamount,0)
FROM Acutaltable
```